# Python - Sort a list of (positive and negative) integers by number

Tags: python

I have a list of list that includes positive and negative numbers. I need to sort this list based on the numbers (regardless to the sign if it is positive or negative).

Example: `[[-4, 9], [1, 2, 3], [-9, 2], [-8, 7], [2]]`

Results should be like: `[[1, 2, 3], [2], [2,-9], [-4, 9], [7, -8]]`

Comment: 'based on' is not explicit, please explain exactly how it should be sorted. Do you mean sort by first digit or each no matter it's sign ?

Comment: how are the lists sorted?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, use `sorted` with `abs` and `len`:

```
sorted([sorted(i, key=abs) for i in l], key=lambda x:(abs(x[0]), len(x)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2], [2, -9], [-4, 9], [7, -8]]
```